# Controlling Excel through VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, excel

I am able to successfully add my Excel "database" into my program. However, I'm a bit confused on how the Search function and Save feature work. I want to make it so that the user can edit text directly in the DataGridView and save their work (Which would save to the local excel file). I was following a tutorial, but my program is not working according to theirs, specifically the Search and Save button. Every time I type and click on "Search", I always get the error

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Link to tutorial I Was folloing:
 [Save, Search, Edit Excel from VB.NET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGk_LMLsJzA)

Essentially, I want to make it so that the user can control the excel form through VB.NET. I know this seems a bit useless (Since the user can just open the excel file anyway...) but I'm just experimenting as of now (relatively new to VB.NET).

My code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs)
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)

    With DataGridView1
        .DataSource = dt
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Id"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Nama Agen"
        .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Try
        FillDataGridView("select * from [Data Agen$] where id='" & txtID.Text.ToString() & "'")
        txtName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "insert into [Data Agen$]values('" & txtID.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "')"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [Data Agen$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("Successfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Update [Data Agen$] set [nama agen] = '" & txtName.Text & "' where id='" & txtID.Text & "'"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [Data Agen$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("Successfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    FillDataGridView("select * from [Data Agen$]")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cn.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\FEQH\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\exceltester\test.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    cn.Open()
    FillDataGridView("select * from [Data Agen$]")
    Button1.Visible = False
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If the Excel ID column is numeric you dont need the ticks in the SQL.  The error message is saying that the datatype you pass (string) doesnt match the Excel file.  Also, there are numerous bad ideas in that code/video.  You'd be much better off visiting MSDN than YouTube.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the duplicate result. I searched quite a bit before posting  this... Odd I didn't find it!